# Select id, max(value) - Can't get right id

Tags: mysql, select, max, rows

I have a table with some columns where I want to select 'id' and the highest 'value'.

When I do :

```
SELECT id, max(value) AS highest_value FROM table WHERE id_column='2' GROUP BY id
```

I get the right values of id, but I get multiple rows (normal behavior).

So as I want only the id of the highest value I do the standard request which is :

```
SELECT id, max(value) AS highest_value FROM table WHERE id_column='2'
```

Then I have another id for the same highest_value... Can't understand why.

Comment: That is what happens when you have columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY` and not aggregated.  The query returns values from *indeterminate* rows.  Simply don't use this MySQL (mis)feature which is incompatible with other databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
ORDER BY highest_value DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If id is unique, you don't even need the `max()` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE id_column = '2'
ORDER BY value DESC
LIMIT 1
;
```

Comment: Even if id is unique, he's still need `max` and `group by`. different story if the unique column was `id_column`

Comment: "I want only the id of the highest value" his initial query is GROUPing by id, at which point id_column was only relevant for initial filtering.